# Increase account association rep 'bump' from 100 to 200

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, association

Many, if not most, new-user helper features turn off by the time you get to 200 rep, for instance:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37963/why-does-serverfault-always-show-the-add-comment-box-on-answers

Please consider increasing the 100 rep gain for associating accounts to 200 to get seasoned users past all the new-user limiters that have been added in the last year.

Comment: Let's make it 10k so I get all the cool tools on all the sites.

Comment: Why not 100k so that we can all be Jon Skeet?

Comment: Do you really want someone who has 10k on Superuser moderating discussions on Stackoverflow, hmmmMMMMMM?

Comment: @Pollyanna: You're right! SuperUsers get -5k on SU for associating with the real sites.

Comment: I don't want any one person moderating discussions anywhere. That is where most of our problems come from.

Comment: @Pollyanna: Does Superuser actually exist or are you just putting me on?

Comment: @mmyers: It is the same as the Christian concept of 'hell'. It is a place we threaten users with if they misbehave (like calling someone a dick, for instance). It is rumored to be inhabited by the stupidest people on the internet and capable of sucking all the life from you within mere seconds. I should know - I get sent there every time I am banned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I signed on at Meta and associated my account with SF (just yesterday) I was rather surprised that I received any rep at all. Why should I (or anyone else)? It makes absolutely no difference how I may be "performing" on any other site. On this one I'm a complete noob and expected to be treated accordingly. Under the circumstances I think 100 rep is very generous.

Comment: Well... I think it's very reasonable. You already know when and how to upvote, downvote, comment etc. That is the same everywhere. You are also obviously not a spambot or a sockpuppet. So you get 100 to remove all restrictions aimed at spambots, sockpuppets, and people who don't know when to upvote/downvote/comment.

Answer (score 8):

[From comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37966/increase-account-association-rep-bump-from-100-to-200/37970#37970):

> 100 is the optimal number without going too high -- that gives you vote up, flag, leave comments, edit cwiki, and vote down. What else is really necessary? Also, reduced advertising at 200 is something you should still have to earn IMO. – Jeff Atwood

Comment: Anyone who _wants_ reduced advertising can already get rid of it entirely, so 200 is not really relevant IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating an account association should give you diamond mod powers!

Comment: Why stop at diamond? I want spade mod powers!

Comment: I want waffle mod powers.

Comment: I think creating an account association should give you diamond waffle powers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should automatically be thought of as being a trusted user on ServerFault just because you had enough rep to get the association bump on StackOverflow. I think 100 is the maximum I would ever want to see, and even that I think is too much.

This doesn't seem to go with the grain of reputation relating to how much the system trusts you.

Comment: I believe there is a correlation between how much a user can be trusted on one site and on another within the trilogy.  Keep in mind that they are only separate so that we can keep SO on topic.  200 doesn't yield many benefits, all it does is say, "I suppose you aren't going to link spam, image spam, and don't need help understanding how the system works."  If someone has significant rep on any other site, then why can't we trust them with the rather minor limitations imposed on beginners for a given site?

Comment: Note that I'm talking about trust here - not reputation, and 200 is still a very low value of trust.

Comment: I don't see why you should gain any trust or rep. You did nothing to deserve it. I should point out that I feel that way about me and serverfault and superuser as well.

Comment: I agree, 100 is the optimal number without going too high -- that gives you vote up, flag, leave comments, edit cwiki, and vote down. What else is really necessary? Also, reduced advertising at 200 is something you should still have to earn IMO.