# How many rep for an accepted answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I've had a look through the FAQ and either I'm going blind or there's no mention of how much rep an acceptance earns. On SF it's 15, so I naturally expected the same on MSO. However, when I logged in today, which I do infrequently, I was somewhat astonished to learn I'd reached the daily cap and the mortarboard badge with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37966/increase-account-association-rep-bump-from-100-to-200/38017#38017) answer that received only 2 up votes and an acceptance. Surely that can't be correct?

Answer (score 5):

You've won [Pollyana Lottery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery) that worth 550 points

Comment: Yep.  The yellow border indicates that it was the recipient of a bounty.  Hover over the green checkmark and it shows you in the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip on the accept arrow will tell you what's going on.

Also, if the accept arrow is "glowing" that's a bounty accept.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I thought the "glow" was just a cosmetic difference between sites and never thought to hover over it. Yippy, my first bounty!